# How to verify data integrity of data folders after data recovery in MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, recovery

I wonder if there is a way to verify data integrity of data folders from a data-recovered hard disk, both MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Comment: If you have enabled [data-checksums](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html#APP-INITDB-DATA-CHECKSUMS) in Postgres it will automatically verify that and you can use `pg_verify_checksums` manually before starting the instance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately I have never used `-data-checksums` that apparently must only be set at the point of cluster creation. Thank you.

Comment: If you use a tool like [pgbackrest](https://pgbackrest.org/) it will automatically verify your backups.

Comment: Check Percona Toolkit for checksumming MySQL.  But you need checksums before the dump, too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way in PostgreSQL is to run something like

```
pg_dumpall >/dev/null
```

which will scream if it encounters table corruption.

However, that won't test index integrity. For that, PostgreSQL v11 has the [amcheck](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/amcheck.html) extension.